# Dynamic allocation for extern global variables

Tags: c, memory, extern

I have a global variable inside a shared library that contains an `int*`.

From inside my program when i try to allocate memory to it, I receive a `double free or 
memory corruption error` from `glibc`. The funny thing is, that on a newest version of glibc this does not happen.

the code is like this:

`typedef struct{
   int a;
   int b;
   mytype_t *t;
} A`

In the library I have

`A *a;`

In the code 

`a = malloc ( sizeof ( A ) );
a->t = malloc ( sizeof( *t) );`

The first malloc works fine, only when I do the second I have problems. When I try to free a->list the above error comes into place. `a` is not freed before a->list.

Thank you.

`**EDIT**`

I have fixed the issue, but I do not really know why. I used calloc instead of malloc and instead of `malloc( sizeof(*t) )`, I used `calloc ( sizeof ( mytype_t ) )`;

Comment: What you've presented is fine... we need more info or code

Comment: Do you by any chance first free `a` and then `a->list`?

Comment: No. I first free a->list

Comment: I kind of fixed it by putting `int *list` outside the structure. Then I have no problems.

Comment: You're freeing `a->list` before you allocate any memory to `a`?

Comment: It should by `malloc(sizeof(struct A))` shouldn't it? Or even better: `a = malloc(sizeof(*a))`

Comment: I free a->list after allocating memory to a.

Comment: Regarding your "fix": Did you try accessing `a->a` and/or `a->b`?

Comment: @alk `A` must be a typedef for struct A, or it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @alk . Yes a->a and a->b work.

Comment: @teppic: ... or there is another type called `A`.

Comment: Anyway "*I free a->list after allocating memory to a.*" is the reason! Do it the other way round ... - Alloc `a`, alloc `a->list`, free `a->list`, free `a`, then start over.

Comment: @alk - yes, true! (though the code does say `A *a;`)

Comment: @teppic: The `struct` is missing there also. It should be (at least from what is posted):  `struct A * a;`

Comment: This, as usual, is probably obvious if you **post real code**. Your initial question mentions a double free, yet even now not a single `free()` appears in the posted code. You've mentioned nothing about the *usage* of the member-pointer `list`, whether it is *ever* used anywhere where it may be freed by side-effect. Please, **please** post **real code** with a **real** [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the actual problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ok. Thank you for the advice. I will try to conform in the future .

Comment: Have you got [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/)?  If not, and it will run on your machine, then get it.  Now you've got it, use it; it will diagnose where you're going wrong with startling accuracy. Make sure you compile the code for debug. At the moment, your problem could easily be something unrelated that is corrupting the memory, and it is only your code that is spotting the corruption; this is quite common when there are memory management problems.

Comment: Ditto to @JonathanLeffler s comment. If your platform supports valgrind, you're doing yourself a tremendous *disservice* by not using it, *even if you think your code is correct and appears to run without errors.* It honestly is an amazing tool that can expose problems you didn't know you had and that, due to undefined behavior 's nature, just seemed to work when in reality it was a ticking time  bomb. Get it and use it if your platform supports it.

Comment: @coredump please update your question with the clarifications you have given in the comments. Once done, flag the question for "Other" and notify us that the comments can get deleted.